# after login display another viewController but gives error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have followed 2 tutorials and all separate work 100% properly but when putting them together gives me the following error.

> 2014-05-12 14:49:12.638 app-ios[13988:60b] PostData: nick=demo&pass_field=demo
>   2014-05-12 14:49:12.991 app-ios[13988:60b] Response code: 201
>   2014-05-12 14:49:12.992 app-ios[13988:60b] Response ==> {"nick": "demo", "avatar": "img/noavatar.jpg", "name": "Demo User", "success": "1", "id": 9}
>   2014-05-12 14:49:12.993 app-ios[13988:60b] Success: 1
>   2014-05-12 14:49:12.994 app-ios[13988:60b] Login SUCCESS
>   2014-05-12 14:49:13.017 app-ios[13988:60b] -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14edfc30
>   2014-05-12 14:49:13.018 app-ios[13988:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14edfc30'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x30c62f0b 0x3b3f9ce7 0x30c66837 0x30c65137 0x30bb4098 0x33566873 0x33568b71 0x33568ac5 0x335686bf 0x3356bbb3 0x33492305 0x3310e31b 0x33109b3f 0x334a74a1 0x335bf29d 0x335bf0e9 0x335be5a1 0x335be41f 0x335be2f7 0x334a40d5 0x335c1ee5 0x335c11cb 0x334acce3 0x3357c281 0x3357a5f9 0x3375d507 0x8ffbb 0x334c76c7 0x334c7663 0x334c7633 0x334b2d7b 0x334c707b 0x334c6d4d 0x334c1ca7 0x33496e75 0x33495541 0x30c2dfef 0x30c2d4b7 0x30c2bca7 0x30b96769 0x30b9654b 0x35b036d3 0x334f5891 0x90c2d 0x3b8f7ab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

What i'm trying to do after user logs in is show a tableView with some data.

this is SearchViewController.m

```
    //  SearchViewController.m

    #import "SearchViewController.h"

    @interface SearchViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation SearchViewController {
        NSArray *users;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        users = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast",
                   @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and CheesePanini", nil];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [users count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar1.jpg"];

        return cell;
    }

    /*
    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @end
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure your tableViews delegate is wired up to something that implements the UITableViewDatasource protocol

Comment: the tableView is wired with the dataSource and Delegate the whole code is correct but don't know what im doing wrong. need any other data to see whats wrong?

Comment: The error says that you're trying to call tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: on a UIViewController, not your SearchViewController. Have you forgotten to change the class of your controller in IB?

Comment: @rdelmar i updated the question and added an image the TableView is inside a tab bar Controller but i think that every viewController behave as one single entity independent from all views. I just created a class called the same as the other project and copied all code where it should be it logs in well. but when loading the tab on the table view it crashes also the code underlines the following --> return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: i Think is because the tableView is inside a Tab Bar Controller. and i'm adding the delegate and datasource to the View it is located is that correct?

Comment: I think the error has to do with the Tab Bar while loading. Because if i use the tableView on a ViewController alone it works with the login but not when its inside a Tab Controller.

Comment: debug the "users" array when the code perform the return [users count];, and make sure its not nil, and make sure you create @property for your tableView

Comment: @DekelMaman, no don't tell people to synthesize it. You shouldn't do that anymore.

Comment: if he make @property he need to synthesize unless rewrite getter and setter or using self.tableView, or i'm wrong ? maybe I'm doing it wrong :)

Comment: The exception message clearly tells you that an unrecognised selector is being invoked, so there is an object confusion - the object nominated as the data source doesn't implement the data source protocol. And no, @DekelMaman, you no longer need to synthesize properties if you are happy with the default backing variable and setter/getter methods

Comment: thanks for all your answers, sorry for my ignorance. but I'm new developing xCode apps for iOS how can i import the app that works and hook it up with the login with no class and object confusion? because these 2 apps are separate but when i create on the login app a Tab Bar and insert the TableView and create a class file> new file > class. Then copy all code inside .h and .m inside a tab bar view it does not work. thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

The exception message tells you that you have a U`IViewController` nominated as your table data source and delegate that doesn't implement those protocols. Your code says that your delegate/tableview class is `SearchViewController`. Your need to make sure that the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets from your table view reference an instance of a `SearchViewController`.

What is the type of the object shown in your screen shot?